# spring3 mvc @Valid annotation cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I try to use @Valid annotation, but eclipse always gives the "Valid cannot be resolved to a type" error. I m using the spring3 library.

I have imported hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar into my WEB-INF/lib directory. however, this does not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `Valid.class` inside the JAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember the `@Valid` annotation is part of the validation-api JAR which you can find in the lib directory of the Hibernate Validator, as you have already downloaded the Hibernate implementation. The `@Valid` is a part of the javax.validation annotation API. You can add this JAR to your class path to be able to properly reference the annotation.

Answer (score 14):

`@Valid` belongs to [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303). You can get it via maven using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can download it [from this page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA).

Comment: There is no need to add it directly, since JSR-303 implementation is needed anyway, and it has transitive dependency to the API.

Comment: thank you for u reply. yes. i got it work. i just find that there are two types of @Valid annotation. the first type is method level @Valid which is imported from Hibernate Validator jar. The second type is argument level @Valid which is imported from validation-api jar. To use both, just add them in the WEB-INFO/lib.   Thank you again!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue(Maven project). I followed below and it worked:

1. Added below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Save and Maven will automatically download dependency jar files
3. Restart application

Note: Did not have to mention version as it was already defined in Spring Boot Dependencies. Otherwise below should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final